How do I create an unordered list of folder URLs, without the included files?
No matter what I try, I keep getting the files with 'fake' names. All I want is a list of URLs that I can use in later processing, at which time I would select a folder from the list's dropdown in-order to display all its files.
I tried the code below and it is not working - given that the  console.log(foldersURLs) instruction is not producing an on-screen output.
Thank you for your help in advance.
My current code:
`    
Save Folder URLs
<script>
    function saveFolderURLs() {
       let folderInput = document.getElementById('folderInput');
       let folders = folderInput.files;

       // Example: Save URLs to an array or table
       let folderURLs = [];
       for (let i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
           folderURLs.push(folders[i].webkitRelativePath);
       }

       // Now you should have a displayable list of URL's
       console.log(folderURLs);
    }
</script>

`

For some reason, my html code is missing. Here it is:


Save Folder URLs